# Error del servidor cannot create file sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

Cuando ejecuto la app en la que trabajo, me lanza el siguiente error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Cannot create file 'C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MesaDeServicios.mdf' because it
> already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the
> operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be
> created. Check related errors. Descripción: Excepción no controlada al
> ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila
> para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el
> código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot
> create file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MesaDeServicios.mdf' because it
> already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the
> operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be
> created. Check related errors.
>
> Error de código fuente:
> Línea 24:             this.BeforeWrite =
> BeforeWriteNotification; Línea 25:             // look up the entry in
> the database Línea 26:             Cache =
> db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId ==
> userId); Línea 27:             // place the entry in memory Línea 28:
> this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null :
> MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits,"ADALCache"));

Y me manda una excepción al codigo en la linea de la variable Cache

```
public ADALTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
        {
            // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
            userId = signedInUserId;
            this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
            // look up the entry in the database
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            // place the entry in memory
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits,"ADALCache"));
        }
```

La variable la tengo declarada private con UserTokenCache

Comment: El código no tiene NADA que ver con los errores. En alguna parte, tu aplicación intenta crear una base de datos nueva en el servidor de BD y ya existen los archivos asociados a esa BD (por lo que falla).

Comment: `because it already exists.` -> Ya existe.

Comment: Ok, entonces borrando los archivos en la carpeta que me dice podría ser la solución?

Comment: Depende, ¿es una base de datos de información valiosa o es información "descartable" ?

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{dbname}')
  BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE  {dbname}

  END.  Valide si la bd existe antes de crearla.

Comment: Puede ser que también me da error por qué le cambie de nombre  a la BD

Answer (score -1):

Me di cuenta del error que había hecho al cambiarle el nombre a la BD en SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT y solamente reverti el cambio de nombre al que tenía.

Y confirme en la carpeta de DATA si tenia el mismo nombre de la BD

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).